# What is the most damage that can be done in one round on your turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, damage

I was surprised that this question has not been asked.

I want to find out what the most damage that can be done in a single round?

Here are the rules.

- Rules from Official Hardcover books only.
- Any official playable race can be used.
- No optional rules, other than those listed here.
- Multiclassing and feats are permitted.
- Characters can be up to LV 20
- Standard point buy for stats.
- No Magic items.
- No infinite loops we are not trying to break the system.  We are trying to find the maximum damage in a reasonable setting.
- Consistent effects only.  Random elements like wild magic cannot be used.
- Epic Boons are permitted if you use the Aberrant Dragonmark feat.. You can choose the boon you would like.
- No outside help. Permanent summoned creatures are permitted, and considered to have already been summoned.(find steed, familiar, homunculous.. etc..) Their damage can be added to yours in the calculation.
- Assume one average target with no unusual defenses.
- All attacks hit.
- All saves are passed.
- Polymorph is allowed, but I suspect there are better methods.
- Any attack or combination of spells and attacks can be used provided you are following the rules.
- Include the Maximum rolled damage as well as the average damage, where average is calculated using **min+maximum /2** to calculate it.

I understand that a lot of you don't like optimization questions.  But try to leave me a comment before you give me a negative vote. I will address the issue and fix it(If possible).

This post is for people who do enjoy the theory craft and challenge.  I think it will be interesting to find out what the damage limit is.

Comment: Related: [What is the highest single round damage a level 20 character can deal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170030/33707)

Comment: Related: [What is the most damage that can be done in one round to a single target with spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164300), [What is the most damage one can do with a cantrip in one turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157150), [What's the maximum (average) damage that can be dealt in one round by a 20th level character with at least two levels of Fighter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115624),

Comment: Since the clarifications and discussion were getting lengthy I went ahead and [moved them to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111806/discussion-on-question-by-sam-lacrumb-what-is-the-most-damage-that-can-be-done-i) where hopefully that can be done more easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Infinity

The question permits both Epic Boons and mass-simulacra duplication with the stipulation you've already made all the simulacra you can make.  Since there is, in fact, [no real limit on how many simulacra you might have](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/79845/14848) (note you can make them exponentially faster with an Epic Boon), we start the round with an infinite number of simulacra.  Our infinite simulacra then use any of a variety of ways to teleport in, make an attack, and then die (e.g. since we can exceed level 20 be a sorcerer 3/wizard 17/fighter 20 (to avoid going off the multiclass spellcaster charts), start at 1 hp, *quickened Gate*, attack target, attack self).  This deals infinite damage.

This is hardly the *only* way to deal infinite damage with such weird conditions, but it works.

Comment: If given (nearly) unlimited time to prepare, similarly you could just create a demiplane and fill it with X number of Glyphs of Warding, then Gate the target to it.

Comment: This might be improved if you choose a single attack or spell that the simulacra can be commanded to make, and the writ the damage as a function of the number of simulacra brought to bear.  E.g. simulacra all casting Crown of Stars doing 4d12 dmg.

Comment: The number of simulacra that can target a single opponent will be limited by the range of the attacks.  E.g., they're all using longbows, so how many fit in a 360' radius? * long bow damage.

Comment: This would be true, but the simulacra could arrive at an area and vacate the same area in the span of one round.

Comment: There is no reason to also have 20 levels in fighter if you just get Extra Attack from the Bladesinger Arcane Tradition. Also, I think the question was updated to limit the levels to 20.